# C programming structure access

Tags: c, linux

I found this line in Linux Audio drivers `soc-core.c` inside `sound` folder:

```
int regsize = codec->driver->reg_word_size * 2;
```

Can anybody please explain the meaning of `* 2`?

Comment: You'll kick yourself; it means multiply by two, of course.

Comment: @meda: that's terribly insulting to MathOverflow...it's for professional mathematicians.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because * just close! *

Comment: How could they possibly even let you read the sources?

Comment: @devnull: [it ain't hard](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/soc/soc-core.c)

Comment: @nneonneo You missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the contents of `codec->driver->reg_word_size` by 2. I guess this is a translation between size in words to size in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplies that value by 2.  That's all it does

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can just guess, but it looks like this:
`codec` is a pointer to a structure, which has a pointer to another structure in `driver`, which has a member variable `reg_word_size` (which it seems is, like the name says, the size of a register word). This value gets doubled (*2).

This could be, like the other answer says, a conversion between bytes and words. However, it could probably also just mean that this `regsize` should be twice as big as the `reg_word_size`.